How to break looped command in Bash, specially in make recipe
I have this make recipe.
run_pipelines:
    @[ "${filter}" ] || ( filter="."; ) && \
    filter=$$(echo "$$filter" | sed -e 's/\./.*/g') && echo $${filter}"<3" && \
    echo "\033[1;34m#######Running Pipelines for $${filter}#######\033[0m" && \
    find v2/services -type f -regex ".*$${filter}.*.jsonnet" -print0 | \
    xargs -r -0 -I {} bash -c 'echo -e "\033[1;32mjsonnet {} \033[0m"; jsonnet {} || exit $$?'
.PHONY: run_pipelines

It loops through all jsonnet files and run jsonnet command.
I want to it fail and stop immediately after a single jsonnet command fails.
I have tried few things but nothing working.

something like set -o ; set pipefail`?

Get rid of the [ "$filter ] || filter=..  Instead, just use ${filter:-.} on its first occurrence.  ${var:-default} expands to "$var" if "$var" is non-empty, and to default otherwise.

If you want terminal escape codes to add color or attributes, query the terminfo database with tput.  (eg, instead of echo "\033[1;34m", use  tput bold; tput setaf 4

xargs -I{} bash -c '...{}...' is a route to serious security bugs; don't ever substitute data into code directly like that. Instead, pass find's results into bash as arguments and write your bash code to iterate over its argument list; xargs bash -c 'for arg; do ..."$arg"...; done' _ (no -I needed on the xargs) doesn't have the same risks.

Really, you don't even need xargs at all in that case -- can use find ... -exec bash -c 'for arg; do ..."$arg"...; done' _ {} + and let find do the work of xargs splitting the results up into separate commands.

The way you're actually using $filter, you don't even need a default value.  Or at least, using . as the default value does nothing for you.  Also, you don't need sed for simple string replacement operations.  Consider filter="${filter//./.*}".

It looks mistaken that at the beginning of your recipe you use "${filter}" (a make variable), but everywhere else within you use $${filter} (an escaped reference to a shell variable).  Even if you're counting on make importing filter from its environment, I urge you to be consistent here.

Note that find's predicates -name, -iname, -path, and -ipath recognize glob-style patterns.  If that is sufficient for your needs then I would use it. The -regex predicate is less portable, and more prone to error.  For example, writing .jsonnet where you probably meant [.]jsonnet or \.jsonnet (stylistically, I prefer the former).

If your find has -quit, instead of piping into xargs and bash:
...
find v2/services -type f -regex ".*$${filter}.*.jsonnet" -print0 | \
xargs -r -0 -I {} bash -c 'echo -e "\033[1;32mjsonnet {} \033[0m"; jsonnet {} || exit $$?'
...

just use find's -exec option and then you can test its return directly:
...
find v2/services -type f -regex ".*$${filter}.*.jsonnet" \
    -printf '\033[1;32mjsonnet %p \033[0m\n" \
    \( -exec jsonnet {} \; -o -quit \)
...

Note that the return value will follow find's specification. For the GNU version, this is:

find exits with status 0  if  all  files  are  processed  successfully, greater  than 0 if errors occur.  This is deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value is non-zero, you should not rely  on the correctness of the results of find.

The value will be non-zero if -quit is invoked but can be non-zero even if all jsonnet processes succeeded. (e.g. unreadable directory that find could not enter)

Agreed. Piping into xargs has little advantage over find -exec in this case, where the main objective is to execute a single command on each file matched, separately.  This alternative not only stops file processing as soon as one fails, but it also stops the file search, which could be valuable if the tree being searched is large.
